# Getting Unmatched Result Values in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to execute a cypher query to  Match a result set for a case where a "User" "Writes" a "Post" and also match if any "Reply" has been received for the respective "Post" with a relation name as "ReplyOf". Following is the query that I have tried.

```
match (user1:User)-[:WRITES]->(p:Post)
optional match (r:Reply)-[:REPLYOF]->(p)
where user1.Email="xyz@xyz.com"
return p,r
```

My Problem is that instead of returning only the particular Post and Reply(if any available) as per the condition provided in the where clause, I am getting the entire Posts results of all users. What could be the reason for such occurence? One thing I have noted is that, if I exclude the optional match statement from query then it provides the correct matched post as per the where condition. Please suggest what could be wrong with query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the where clause to before optional match